# C++ iterator to specific type

Tags: c++, c++11

How do you create an iterator that restricts the underlying type? For example, I want to create functions like the following:

```
void functionThatOperatesOnPointSequence(PointIterator begin, PointIterator end);
```

Where the sequence of `Point` objects may be stored in different ways. My use case would have the additional complexity that `Point` would be a templated type. i.e. `Point<int>` or `Point<double>` would be equally valid.

Solutions using C++11/14 or Boost are valid and preferable.

Comment: Have you created something? It's stack overflow, so you should ask question providing that you have done some effort. Not ask for ready made solution.

Comment: `PointIterator::operator*` can return only one type of objects. `PointIterator` should probably be a template argument.

Comment: `is_a_point<std::decay_t<decltype(*begin)>>::value` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit of template metaprogramming.  `is_template_instance` takes a template that takes only types, and a type, and returns true if that second type is an instance of the first template.

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
struct is_template_instance:std::false_type{};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct is_template_instance<Z,Z<Ts...>>:std::true_type{};
```

Now, we want to query the value type of the iterator.  We can use `std::iterator_traits` directly, or use an alias like this:

```
template<class It>
using it_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
```

We compose the two above to write a `is_point_iterator` template:

```
template<class It>
using is_point_iterator = is_template_instance< Point, it_value_type<It> >;
```

Note that if you pass this non-iterators, it may not fail in a friendly manner, or it may return the wrong result (`std::iterator_traits` does not guarantee sensible return values for non-iterators).

But that tends to be caught in template bodies.

```
template<class PointIterator,
  class=std::enable_if_t< is_point_iterator<PointIterator>::value >
>
void functionThatOperatesOnPointSequence(PointIterator begin, PointIterator end) {
  // ...
}
```

there is only limited usefulness.

You could extract the value type from the PointIterator in a more SFINAE friendly manner, for example:

```
template<class It>
using it_value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<It>())>;
```

if you need SFINAE support.

Comment: A question is also if derived class from `Point<T>` should be considered as `Point` or not. (Not in your case currently).

Comment: @Jarod42 I can think of an easy solution (function overloading based) that doesn't distinguish between a type derived from `Point<T>` and something with an `operator Point<int>&()`.  Possibly I should refactor to `is_iterator_over< element_test, It >` to make that easier to work with.